# Node.js - Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm struglling with Node.js Promises...

The **code** method must returns a Promise which resolves with a String.
The resolved String depends on the value of the name and language properties of the Developer instance:

Output Example:
language: nodejs. Then `console.log("Hello, Nicole!")`
language: java. Then `System.out.println("Hello, Nicole!")`
language: python. Then `print("Hello, Nicole!")`

For any other language, the returned Promise should reject with an Error instance with a respective message: **Unsupported language**.

Please, could anyone check if this code method correct?
I assume it isn't, please, what's wrong and why?

```
    class developer {
        constructor(name, language) {
            this.name = name
                this.role = language
        }
    
        getName() {
            return this.name
        }
    
        setName(name) {
            this.name = name
        }
    
        getLanguage() {
            return this.language
        }
    
        setLanguage(language) {
            this.language = language
        }
    
        code() {
            this.getName();
            this.getLanguage();
    
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
                if (this.language === 'nodejs') {
                    console.log(' console.log("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
                } else if (this.language === 'java') {
                    console.log('System.out.println("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
                } else if (this.language === 'python') {
                    console.log('print("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
                } else {
                    console.log('Unsupported language: ' + this.language);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    let mydeveloper = new developer();
    mydeveloper.code();
```

Comment: Why is a promise necessary here?

Comment: why promise? nodejs is not a language, and your promise is not returning anything

Comment: promise is not really required here. If required you need to either invoke the `resolve` or `reject` to complete the operation. Otherwise the promise will be in a pending state

Comment: read this page, what you want to achieve is easy ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You could return a promise that resolves to the expected string, e.g. `if (this.language === 'nodejs') { return Promise.resolve(' console.log("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")'); }`. The promise has to resolve to a string. It should not print a string.

Comment: Look up `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). Creating a new promise object for this task is more complicated than returning a call to one of these static methods.

Comment: You don't need promise here in your case.

Comment: The requirement is to use a promise, but I still studying and to be honest I didn't get its idea yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you return a Promise, you have to define when it is resolved and when it's rejected.

```
class developer {
  constructor(name, language) {
    this.name = name
    this.role = language
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name
  }

  setName(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  getLanguage() {
    return this.language
  }

  setLanguage(language) {
    this.language = language
  }

  code() {
    this.getName();
    this.getLanguage();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (this.language === 'nodejs') {
        resolve('console.log("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
      } else if (this.language === 'java') {
        resolve('System.out.println("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
      } else if (this.language === 'python') {
        resolve('print("Hello, ' + this.name + '!")');
      } else {
        reject('Unsupported language: ' + this.language);
      }
    });
  }
}

let mydeveloper = new developer('John Doe', 'English');

// Will print out -> Unsupported language: undefined
mydeveloper
  .code()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// Set language to nodejs
mydeveloper.setLanguage('nodejs');

// Will print out -> console.log("Hello, John Doe!")
mydeveloper
  .code()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// Set language to java
mydeveloper.setLanguage('java');

// Will print out -> System.out.println("Hello, John Doe!")
mydeveloper
  .code()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// Set language to python
mydeveloper.setLanguage('python');

// Will print out -> print("Hello, John Doe!")
mydeveloper
  .code()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```